# restore a PostgreSQL backup

Tags: postgresql, bigdata, backup, restore

I am new in postgresql, and I have a big dataset which is a postgresql backup. I have problem to import this dataset to my PostgreSQL. 
Actually, this is a "pgdata" format, consists of some files and folders. One of these folders (base folder) has all the main files, (2000 files, each of which is 1 GB). But all of these files are in the "file" format, with no extension!! 
I would be so grateful if you could give me some advice on this issue and help me to restore this backup.
Best,

Comment: try `createdb   -D  PGDATA_LOCAL  dbname`,  PGDATA_LOCAL is the path of your `pgdata`.

Comment: usually, basebackup is supposed to replace all the content of "data" folder of PG(where it is installed), after stopping the service. After that you are supposed to create a recovery file config for that and start service

Answer (score 0):

From your description I guess that you have a physical backup, a copy of the data files like `pg_basebackup` creates.

If there is a `backup_label` file in the backup, and all the required WAL files are in the `pg_xlog` (or `pg_wal`) directory, then all you have to do is start the server on the data directory (`pg_ctl start -D <directory here>`) and wait until recovery has completed.

Then you can use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to extract the data from this new PostgreSQL cluster and import it into the destination.